# Headers h2 to h4 not the color they should be, possibly incorrect syntax somewhere?

Tags: html, css

Cannot work this one out. My headers from `h2` through to `h4` are white in color instead of black. Everything seems to work is it should when removing `color: white;` from a class that isn't even being used on the page (but is in the stylesheet):

```
.right_content_default h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    color: white;
}
```

The only thing I can think of is a possible syntax issue, but I can't locate it in the stylesheet.

Here's the fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sD3T2/)

Comment: You might want to consider checking the syntax of your HTML too -- it has a few nesting issues. (They're not the cause of the problem in this case, though)

Comment: That's probably because I quickly took a few chunks out of it for the jsfiddle, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your selector is looking for `"h1 inside .right_content_default, or any of h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"`. Nothing it telling it to only apply the white colour to headings inside that class name, other than `h1`.

The correct CSS is:

```
.right_content_default h1, .right_content_default h2, .right_content_default h3,
.right_content_default h4, .right_content_default h5, .right_content_default h6 {
    color:white
}
```

But in some browsers you can do this:

```
.right_content_default :matches(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) {color:white}
```

Comment: @Kolink don't abuse the `code` tag then, half the content you've shoved into the code tag isn't actually code.

Comment: @sooper I'm not sure. It's CSS4, so I would guess Firefox and Chrome will adopt it in due time.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
      .right_content_default h1,
      .right_content_default h2,
      .right_content_default h3,
      .right_content_default h4,
      .right_content_default h5,
      .right_content_default h6 {
       color: white;
      }
```

Comment: +1 (and it's got the proper formatting of new lines for each! ) i think if you explained this just a bit, it would be a really great answer